# I want to change the text of textView of cardview on click of textView in android

Tags: android

I have created cardview with recyclerview and on single card i have placed four textView and i want to change the text of textView on click of same textView.
When i am trying to do this it is applying on others card also. Like i have four card and every cards have like textView, When i am changing the text from like to liked on click like facebook and after that loading more data on scroll . But after loading data i am seeing that like textView already changed on newly loaded cards also by default.Here is my Adapter:

```
package common;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.rate.sky.rate.LoginActivity;
import com.rate.sky.rate.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.targetActivity;
import static android.R.attr.width;
import static com.rate.sky.rate.R.attr.height;
import static com.rate.sky.rate.R.attr.title;

/**
 * Created by sky on 12/18/2016.
 */

public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    UserAuth auth;
    private Activity activity;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private ArrayList<ListItem> list;
    ListItem listItem;


    public CardAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<ListItem> listVal){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list=listVal;

    }

    public ListItem getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_card_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        listItem =  getItem(position);
        try {
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext())
                    .getImageLoader();
            imageLoader.get(listItem.getUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.thumbnail,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
            holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(listItem.getUrl(), imageLoader);
            holder.textViewContent.setText(listItem.getTitle());
        }catch (Exception e){
          Log.d("Error--",e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView thumbnail;
        public ImageView imageShare, imageComment, imageVote, imageDownvote;
        public TextView textViewVoteButton, textViewDownVoteButton, textViewCommentButton, textViewContent;
        public TextView txtVoteCount, txtDownVoteCount, txtCommentCount;
        public Button rateButton;
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent;
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            auth = new UserAuth(itemView.getContext());
            thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            rateButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            imageShare = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            imageComment = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewComment);
            textViewContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textViewVoteButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textViewDownVoteButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            textViewCommentButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            imageVote = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewVote);
            imageDownvote = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDownvote);
            txtVoteCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVoteCount);
            txtDownVoteCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDownvote);
            txtCommentCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewComments);
            /*Custome chrome tab view*/
            intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            // Set toolbar(tab) color of your chrome browser
            intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
            customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
            /*End*/
            /*
              Changing the text of textview 
            */
            imageVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (auth.getLoginWith().equals("G") || auth.getLoginWith().equals("F")) {
                        vote();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

            textViewVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (auth.getLoginWith().equals("G") || auth.getLoginWith().equals("F")) {
                        vote();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });



        }

        public void vote() {
            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 180, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(400);
            imageVote.startAnimation(anim);
            ColorStateList mList = textViewVoteButton.getTextColors();
            int color = mList.getDefaultColor();
            if (color == Color.BLUE) {
                textViewVoteButton.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                textViewVoteButton.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the code ...

Comment: Thanks for reply @Selvin but can you suggest that what kind of problem may be ?

Comment: The problem is that you don't know how to ask the question ... Programmers doesn't use magic orbs, so it's hard toguess where is the problem without code

Answer (score 1):

The RecyclerView recycles views, which means that when you scroll it takes an already existing view and repurposes it for another entry in the list. That view doesn't get magically reset, it stays exactly the way you left it when it was used for the previous entry.

In your `vote` method, you apparently change the color of the text view when the user clicks the entry, but you do not reset the color to a default state when it gets reused for another entry. So it just stays whatever color it was before.

You need to track somehow what entries have already been voted on (not in the viewholder or the view, but somewhere in your model) and then set the correct color for *every* view in your onBindViewHolder method.

Basically, you *always* have to manually reset *all* changes made to the view in your onBindViewHolder method.